# How to compare voice command input by user to hard coded strings

Tags: java, android, api, voice

I am currently working on an app that takes user input by voice command. The program recognizes the words using the google api. I want to be able to compare the user voice input to hard coded strings. My problem is that I do not know how to code this function. I am using if else statements to match the hard coded string, but the Toast is always the wrong one. Could anyone please guide me? Thank you for your time!

```
/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));

            if(txtSpeechInput.equals("weather")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It's a difficult question... I'm sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        }

        break;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: At the point where you compare `txtSpeechInput.equals("weather")` what is the value of `txtSpeechInput`?

Comment: the value is whatever words are spoken into the google api. I want to have those words be compared and matched to hardcoded strings, like "hello" for example. If I say "Hello" txtSpeechInput will display "Hello" in a textview, then I want to compare it to a hardcoded string "hello" I hope this makes sense

Comment: Continue.... "and even though i say "weather" it still does not match in my if else statement

Comment: Oh hang on. `txtSpeechInput` is your TextView? Try `result.get(0).equals("weather")`

Comment: Yes txtSpeechInput is the TextView. I added after the (result.get(0).equals("weather") code but no luck :(   Error says: "Cannot resolve method setText(boolean) any idea?

Comment: That goes in your if statement. Replace `txtSpeechInput` with `result.get(0)`. See my answer.

Comment: Cool!!!! This works! Thank you Jack!!! I appreciate it! Only problem I have now is that even though I say other words that are not "weather" the else statement does not pop up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80840/discussion-between-jack-and-user3078406).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing your String to a TextView object instead of directly to the data.

Try `if( result.get(0).equals("weather") ) { ... }`

Or at least `if( txtSpeechInput.getText().toString().equals("weather") ) { ... }`